# How to keep the processing time within OnSleep()?

Tags: forms, xamarin, uwp

I am currently developing a Xamarin Forms UWP application. I am trying to save data when OnSleep () is called when the application ends, but it ends in the middle of the process. How can I continue processing to the end?

I tried how much processing time can be secured in OnSleep ().

in App.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
    Tracer.WriteLine("OnSleep In");
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Tracer.WriteLine("OnSleep Out");
}
```

Expected result

14:25:21.414    OnSleep In

14:25:23.414    OnSleep Out

Actual result (never comes OnSleep Out)

14:25:21.414    OnSleep In

14:25:21.827    OnSleep In

program ended

Comment: What you can do is check what the current status of your Task is and then push it to a background Task check this for an initial understanding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Comment: Different from Android and iOS (your code works fine in iOS and Android platform).You have to create a background task class and register it to run when your application is in background mode.

Comment: Thank you for information. I tried to implement BackgroundTask. Although it moves to BackgroundTask when the application ends, I do not know how to execute or continue the process of the caller with BackgroundTask. Could you tell me the specific method?

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task.